# Nodes for arcs, which angles are calculated simultaneously

Tags: tikz-pgf

TikZ finally enables nodes for arcs since version 3.0.0.

However, there is one problem I came across to. Sometimes angles of the arc are calculated simultaneously, as in `\draw (60:1) arc (30+30:0:1);` This works fine by itself, but when combined with node command, one gets error

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>
                     +
```

Is there any way round this problem?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,auto]
\draw (60:3) -- (0,0) -- (0:3);
\draw (60:1) arc (30+30:0:1);
\draw (60:1) arc (30+30:0:1) node[midway] {$\beta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use such as `node[anchor=south west]` or `node[above, inner sep=5mm]`

Comment: @ferahfeza Yes, these two options work, but do not give desired result.  I wonder why only `midway` has a problem

Comment: It's very interesting! The problem is on second point definition for arc (30+30:0:1). I think You probably try it as `\draw (60:1) arc (60:0:1) node[midway] {$\beta$};`, it works!?

Comment: @ferahfeza your snippet works for me. Pygmalion, is there a specific need for the calculation in this case?

Comment: @PaulGessler In the example above calculation is of course senseless.  I just wanted to make MWE.  But I often draw very complicated arcs, that are controlled by pre-defined values, e.g. `\def\angle{70}` and `\draw (0,0) arc (\angle+20:\angle+50:2);`

Answer (score 1):

It works with

```
\draw (0:1) arc (0:30+30:1) node[midway,right] {$\beta$};
```

I could not make out the reason why it won't work with

```
\draw (60:1) arc (30+30:0:1) node[midway] {$\beta$};
```

for now.

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,auto]
\draw (60:3) -- (0,0) -- (0:3);
%\draw (60:1) arc (30+30:0:1);
\draw (0:1) arc (0:30+30:1) node[midway,right] {$\beta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that the node is drawn to the right of mid point. To see things more clearly add `draw` option to the node.

Here are some ways of cheating. You can calculate the addition outside. One method is below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,auto]
\draw (60:3) -- (0,0) -- (0:3);
\foreach \ang [evaluate=\ang as \Ang using int(\ang+30)] in {30} {
\draw (\Ang:1) arc (\Ang:0:1) node[midway] {$\beta$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.  However, the MWE serves only for presenting the problem.  In fact I often calculate both, starting and ending angle, e.g. `\draw (0,0) arc (\angle+20:\angle+50:2);`, so this really does not solve my problems.

Comment: @Pygmalion Still I have no clue. But there is a work around to evaluate it outside. See my last edit. Hope it will be useful.

Comment: Yes, outside evaluation is a possibility, and the last resort, if nothing else works.